# A Question of Division Algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let p be an integer with p is not equal to 0,+1, and -1. 
Prove that p is prime if and only if p has the following property;
Whenever p|mn, then either p|m or p|n.

Comment: The final phrase you write is usually taken to be the definition of prime. What definition of prime are you starting from? Exactly two positive divisors?

Comment: @rschweib Clearly that is so, and that is the case for most elementary number theory textbooks. The other definition of prime is usually not met till a course in abstract algebra (or advanced number theory).

Comment: @BillDubuque I did not get pinged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $p$ is prime and does not divide $m$. Then $p$ and $m$ are coprime, hence there exist integers $r$ and $s$ with $rp+sm=1$. Therefore $rpn+smn=n$. Since $p$ divides the left-hand side of this equation (since $p\mid mn$), it follows that $p\mid n$. This shows the claim.

Comment: +1 Great, although it should probably say "and that $p$ is prime" to the first line (the post does not already assume so.)

Comment: Thank you ! Yes, I thought $p$ is a prime. I will edit.